# How to make one to many relationship from two sources in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have an `Artist` Model which has many `Reviews`. Also `Artists` has many `Gigs` which in turn also has many `reviews`. The reviews can dierctly come for the `Artist` and as well as from the `Gigs` that the `Artist` does. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Artist.first.reviews
# Should return reviews directly from the artist as well as from artist.gigs
```

How do I model this? Should I define a new method like `all_reviews` in my model that fetches and merges the `reviews` or is there any straight forward way through associations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymorphic association helps you to address this problem. See [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

In you case the code looks like:

```
Class Artist
  has_many :reviews, as: reviewable
  has_many :gigs

  def all_reviews
    reviews + gigs.reviews
  end
end

Class Gig
  has_many :reviews, as: reviewable
  belongs_to :artist
end

Class Reviewable
  belongs_to :reviewable, polymorphic: true
end
```

You can also make the method all_reviews as an association but it makes sense mainly if you intend to use association's methods (add to collection, look up through children etc.), not just fetch the data.

Comment: Just wanted to avoid that all_reviews method for syntatical sugar. I guess all_reviews is the way to go.

Comment: Won't this load the entire reviews for a given artist just to perform the `+` operation? I used the `OR` thing just to avoid using the `+` operator due to the heavy performance implications (out of memory issues and such)

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with the `all_reviews` method. That being said, it's interesting how to optimize it.

Are you using a polymorphic field or your `Review` model `belongs_to :gig` and `belongs_to :artist`?

If the case is the second one, you can do something like this in your `Review` model:

```
def all_reviews
  Review.where(['reviews.gig_id IN ? OR reviews.artist_id = ?', gigs, id])
end
```

This should be fine, however in case you are using a polymorphic field, let's call it `reviewer`, you can do something like this:

```
def all_reviews
  Review.where([
    '(reviews.reviewer_type = ? AND reviews.reviwer_id IN ?) OR (reviews.reviewer_type = ? AND reviews.review_id = ?)',
    'Gig', gigs, 'Artist', id
  ])
end
```

Both should be fine. Please notice I didn't manually test code so there might be errors

Comment: Yes. I am using polymorphic associations. I guess all_reviews is the way to go.